# Cannot import itextpdf 5 in IntelliJ - Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, itext

I'm trying to use itextpdf5 but IntelliJ doesn't seem to find the package. I'm using Maven to manage the dependencies and this is what I added to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I try to import the package in one of my .java files with:

```
import com.itextpdf;
```

But what I obtain is "java: package com does not exist".
I've tried to do mvn clean, mvn install, basically mvn "everything", restarting the IDE, but nothing changes. Am I missing something?

Here is my full pom.xml file, in case it's needed

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.thatdc</groupId>
<artifactId>BreadAndButter</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.thatdc.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import a package like that in Java.

Import a specific class:

`import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;`

Or import a full package:

`import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;`